# How to create multiple theme in cakephp 2.2.5-0 version

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp 2.2.5-0 version to develop my project. I want to create a separate theme so that i can built new theme without  modify the default theme files.

Problem is when i google for it. I got solution with older version. Current package (cakephp 2.2.5-0) folder structure is not same as older version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using themes is described well in the [official docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/themes.html), and covers CakePHP version 2.2.5.